# Date difference between dates in Javascript and datediff mysql not equal

Tags: javascript, mysql

I have a javascript function that returns the number of days between two dates, but it seems to return a day less then what mysql dateDiff function would return

```
 function dateDiffInDays() {
    var date1 = new Date("05/30/2012");
    var date2 = new Date("11/29/2013");
    var diffDays = parseInt((date2 - date1) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)); 

    alert(diffDays );
}
```

if I use this two dates in the mysql function, i get 548, where as with javascript, I get 547, what does mysql and excel do with their functions thats different with javascript

Comment: ...are you sure? I get 548 in JS...

Comment: Oh, and you should probably be *explicitly* using `.getTime()` on your `date2` and `date1`.

Comment: I also get 548 in javascript

Comment: Yes Im sure, just tried it on an online code editor, same thing, 547 days

Comment: I also got 548. http://jsfiddle.net/hA4y4/

Comment: Both MySQL and JavaScript get the same result. [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d41d8/323) and [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wGzXb/2/)

Comment: I get 547 even with the links you guys posted

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: Im using google chrome

Comment: Just tried it in safari, same thing, 547

Comment: Could this be a timezone thing maybe?

Comment: @HoseaKambonde On which system, which timezone?

Comment: Probably. It's weird, though, I thought a timezone problem would just give you something like one-hour differences from DST, not a full day.

Comment: Is there a way one can adjust the Timezone with the Date Object?

Comment: I just added an answer, let us know if that helps.

Comment: Yep, It seems to work now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since we're suspecting a timezone problem, you could try something like this:

```
function dateDiffInDays() {
    var date1 = new Date("05/30/2012");
    var date2 = new Date("11/29/2013");
    var utc1 = Date.UTC(date1.getFullYear(), date1.getMonth(), date1.getDate());
    var utc2 = Date.UTC(date2.getFullYear(), date2.getMonth(), date2.getDate());
    var diffDays = parseInt((utc2 - utc1) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)); 

    alert(diffDays);
}
```

I'm not sure, though. Theoretically, your function should have worked too.

Comment: Ok, this works, now i get 548, so it really was a time zone thing, thanks man

Comment: Well, that's good, but now I hope somebody will explain to me why the previous calculation failed with only a 1-hour difference. Anyone?

Comment: @Aioros @HoseaKambonde Well here the two dates are with differences in `Daylight Saving Time` (with the code of the question). I get a result of `548.0416666666666`  probably with another timezone it is `547.625` with `parseInt` the part after the dot is remove (no rounding), so you have a difference of 1 day with little difference in time. And this should be solved with this answer.

Comment: You're right, I kept thinking we were rounding to the nearest int. Thanks.

Comment: Two notes, always specify a radix with `parseInt` even if not required here (If you always do you won't run into problems) and here i would replace `parseInt` with `Math.floor` because this reflects what it actually done (because the result that is passed to `parseInt` is a float).

Answer (score 0):

They both return 548 days:

**Javascript**

> var date1 = new Date("05/30/2012");
>       var date2 = new Date("11/29/2013");
>       var diffDays = parseInt((date2 - date1) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
>
> diffDays
>   548

**MySQL**

select datediff('2013-11-29','2012-05-30');

548

Answer (score 0):

I get 548 from your previous javascript function. However if there is 1 difference between your javascript and the mysql it is because your javascript calculation is slightly off. Try:

```
function dateDiffInDays() {
    var date1 = new Date("05/30/2012");
    var date2 = new Date("11/29/2013");

    var date1days = parseInt(date1 / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    var date2days = parseInt(date2 / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    var diffDays = date2days - date1days;

    alert(diffDays);
}
```